# Updating Blender and keeping settings

Tags: customization

Yes, I know that I can google it, and I did. My problem is that I've opened files using Blender 2.78c so I can't copy previous settings. Tried the other versions of 2.78 as well but the option isn't there anymore. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about user preferences and startup file, you can access your old blender directory:
go to the appdata/roaming folder (type <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then *%appdata%*) go to the blender foundation folder. Then 2.78 => and open userpref or startup .blend depending on what you want to get in the new version. Then save user prefs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and save user prefs) and save the startup file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

Or alternatively copy these files into 2.78c\config, but I'm not sure if this will work